# AngularJS Inject factory into another factory from the same module

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-services

I'm trying to inject the factory Application into the ApplicationService factory. Both are defined in the same module.

Application factory (application.model.js)

```
(function(Object, coreModule) {
    'use strict';       

    // the factory to expose that allows the creation of application instances
    var ApplicationFactory = function() {
        console.log("Application factory!");
        return {foo: 'bar'};
    }

    coreModule.factory('Application', [ApplicationFactory]);
})(Object, angular.module('core'));
```

ApplicationService factory (application.service.js)

```
(function(coreModule) {
    'use strict';       

    var ApplicationService = function(Application) {
        var api = {
           shout = function() {console.log(Application);}
        };

        return api;
    }   

    ApplicationService.$inject = ['Application'];
    coreModule.factory('ApplicationService', [ApplicationService]); 
})(angular.module('core'));
```

Then I'm injecting ApplicationService factory into a controller and calling the method shout. I get undefined when in the console's log, Application is always undefined. If in a controller I innject Application it works. So i know both factories are working standalone.
Both files are being imported in my index.html.

I've spent hours looking for the issue but I can't find it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see working demo below.

You've got 2 options.

a) Remove square brackets here:

```
coreModule.factory('ApplicationService', ApplicationService)
```

b) Add injected Application as first element before ApplicationService:

```
coreModule.factory('ApplicationService', ['Application', ApplicationService])
```

```js
var app = angular.module('core', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, ApplicationService) {

  ApplicationService.shout();

});


(function(Object, coreModule) {
  'use strict';

  // the factory to expose that allows the creation of application instances
  var ApplicationFactory = function() {
    console.log("Application factory!");
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    };
  };

  coreModule.factory('Application', [ApplicationFactory]);
})(Object, angular.module('core'));


(function(coreModule) {
  'use strict';

  var ApplicationService = function(Application) {
    var api = {
      shout: function() {
        console.log(Application);
      }
    };

    return api;
  };

  ApplicationService.$inject = ['Application'];
  coreModule.factory('ApplicationService', ApplicationService);
})(angular.module('core'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="core">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh god I have no idea why I have done this: coreModule.factory('ApplicationService', [ApplicationService])! Guess it was a long day of work :p Many thanks. For some reason my brain mixed the declaration with the dependency injection annotations :S